# Do pastebin sites have to delete content on request?

Tags: gdpr

A pastebin site, hosted in the US, allows users to post data anonymously. However, its intended purpose is for sharing information about one's computer, including the username (which is sometimes PII). Under GDPR, is the site owner required to allow users to delete posts, even though there's no way to verify who posted? What if all posts are automatically deleted after one day or some other period of time?

Comment: To clarify "username" this is the account name on the user's computer, not any kind of online account name.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, there would still be an obligation to comply with erasure requests – if the data subject can be identified, and if the GDPR applies.

This is a case for Art 11 GDPR: processing which does not require identification.

- The pastebin site is not required to collect identifying info just in order to facilitate later deletion.
- If the site is unable to identify the data subjects, then the data subject rights (like access, rectification, erasure, restriction, or data portability) do not apply. Other rights like the right to be informed and the right to object do remain, though.
- But if the data subject provides sufficient additional information that makes it possible to identify their records, then the data subject rights apply again.

In practice, this is likely going to mean that anyone with access to a paste will be able to request deletion, since the site would have no ability to verify the identity of the data subject beyond the information in the paste.

None of this absolves the site from implementing appropriate technical and organizational measures to ensure the security of this data. Even though the pastes might not be directly identifying, they are personal data and are far from anonymous. Common practices like numbering pastes with a sequential ID or showing recent pastes on a homepage have to be viewed critically. My go-to recommendation is to assign a cryptographically random UUIDv4 ID to the post, so that it is practically impossible for anyone to find the paste unless they were given a link by the uploader.

Your idea to delete pastes after a fairly short retention period is also good. This helps with security, and it is in line with the GDPR's data minimization and storage limitation principles: data may only be kept as long as necessary for its purpose. On the other hand, quick deletion might not be in line with the purpose of these pastes – it all depends on context.

You mention that this is an US-based site. If so, there's a question whether GDPR would even apply. GDPR will apply per Art 3(2) if the data controller is offering its services to people who are in Europe. Here, “offering” does not mean mere availability of the website, but that the data controller intends the service to be used by such people, in particular if the service is somehow targeted or marketed to such people.

Comment: So as long as the site owner doesn't specifically advertise to EU residents, GDPR doesn't apply?

Comment: "If the site is unable to identify the data subjects, then the data subject rights (like access, rectification, erasure, restriction, or data portability) do not apply. Other rights like the right to be informed and the right to object do remain, though." "In practice, this is likely going to mean that anyone with access to a paste will be able to request deletion, since the site would have no ability to verify the identity of the data subject beyond the information in the paste." These two paragraphs appear to contradict each other?

Comment: @Someone Territorial scope of the GDPR is often misunderstood. It doesn't care whether data subjects are EU citizens or if it's possible to access the website. A lot of US sites simply don't have to concern themselves with GDPR. However, the Art 3(2)(a) “targeting criterion” is most clearly applied to paid goods or services (similar to a “nexus” in US law), and it's more difficult to apply to typical websites. The [EDPB has a thorough discussion of relevant factors](https://edpb.europa.eu/our-work-tools/our-documents/guidelines/guidelines-32018-territorial-scope-gdpr-article-3-version_en).

Comment: @Someone Regarding applicability of rights: I can't go to the site and say “please delete my pastes” because they don't know which pastes are from me. But if I say “please delete my pastes, which you can find by looking for entries made today between 11:00 and 15:30 UTC containing the username ‘amon’” then necessary info to enable identification has been provided. But I see no possibility for the site to distinguish between the data subject and impersonators, since any info useful for finding their records would be public.

Comment: Oh, so they have to identify the *data*, not that they are the *poster*?

Comment: Actually, I think I figured out a way to let users verify that they posted something without actually having to keep their personal information. However, there's a chance the user could lose access to the verification code (it will be in a file on their computer, which they could delete or lose due to a computer crash / malware / etc). Would I have to delete the post if a verification system was implemented, but the user (claimed to) had lost the verification code?

Comment: @Someone I think such a solution makes a lot of sense, but the important point is that you're not legally required to implement such a solution. For data subject requests, if you have reasonable doubts about their identity, you can ask for identifying info, see Art 12(6). Usually, being able to log in to an account would be adequate proof of identity. But if the data subject can establish their identity through other means, you'd still have to listen. Recital 57 explains that you “should not refuse to take additional information […] in order to support the exercise of his or her rights”.

Comment: Ultimately, I think the important question is not whether you should strive fulfill data subject rights (if the GDPR applies, the answer will generally be yes). Instead: what are appropriate security measures? Refusing requests from impersonators is part of GDPR compliance as well! Protecting users rights through fulfilling requests and through performing access controls must be balanced. What the correct balance is depends on your specific context, and there cannot be an universal guideline.

Comment: Okay, thank you! For using the verification code, the process will be automated. If someone loses the code, is it enough to have a message saying "please email me if you lost your verification code"?

Comment: Actually, I figured out a way to pseudonymize the data, so it can't identify the user.